# Acess Elastic search instance from Google Dataflow

Tags: elasticsearch, google-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to access my cloud Elastic search nodes from my Cloud Dataflow job. But it is not accessible. I am getting the below exception. Any suggestions on how to fix this would help. Thanks.

```
2016-01-06T19:12:02.573Z: Detail:  (f157f8ce66961b12): Failed task is going to be retried.
2016-01-06T19:12:49.825Z: Error:   (3dc0d192c92b8043): NoNodeAvailableException[None of the configured nodes are available:   [{#transport#-1}{xxx.yyy.aaa.bbb}{xxx.yyy.aaa.bbb:9300}]]
at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.ensureNodesAreAvailable(TransportClientNodesService.java:290)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.execute(TransportClientNodesService.java:207)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.support.TransportProxyClient.execute(TransportProxyClient.java:55)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.doExecute(TransportClient.java:283)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient.execute(AbstractClient.java:347)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:85)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:59)
    at com.zu.bids.rt.dataflow.functions.ElasticSearchIO$CreateDocFromBqRowFn.processElement(ElasticSearchIO.java:77)
```

Comment: Can you ssh into the VM and verify that you can manually reach the address in question?

Comment: Yes.. I can access these VMs and Elastic search outside of Dataflow.

Comment: Can you access Elastic search from one of the Dataflow VMs?

Comment: I resolved it as shown in my post below.

Answer (score 1):

From dataflow node ssh ing failed using (external) ip address or host name. in my dataflow i changed the ip address to node name it worked fine. I couldn't ping using ip address too. But pinging using hostname works.

Atleast my problem is fixed by using elastic search nodes host name in my dataflow jobs.